# Trying to create a random query-based search engine in JavaScript but I'm stuck

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have tried a number of solutions but none of them have worked and I am exhausted in terms of reading documentation at this point. This is my first post on StackOverflow. Please, be gentle.

I am trying to create a random search string query engine. Every time you type in a search form, it selects from an array that has been randomized to use a different search engine string. I can't figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

Here is my code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    var randomlinks=new Array()

    randomlinks[0]="https://duckduckgo.com/?q="
    randomlinks[1]="https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query="
    randomlinks[2]="https://dogpile.com/serp?q="
    randomlinks[3]="https://google.com/search?q="

    function randomlink(){
    window.location=randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]
    }

   </script>  
   </head>

   <body>
    <div class="search-wrapper ">
     <div class="input-holder ">
        <form id="bar" role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="randomlink()">
        <input type="text" class="search-input"/>
        </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </html>
```

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Welcome to s/o, what's the question or issue here?

Comment: What is the problem? Does an error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do (I tried and it works).
In the `form action` add `javascript` to refer to the `function` then you can get the value from the `input` using `getElementById` and pass it as a parameter to your `function` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    var randomlinks=new Array()

    randomlinks[0]="https://duckduckgo.com/?q="
    randomlinks[1]="https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query="
    randomlinks[2]="https://dogpile.com/serp?q="
    randomlinks[3]="https://google.com/search?q="

    function randomlink(link){
    window.location=randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]+link;
    }

   </script>  
   </head>

   <body>
    <div class="search-wrapper ">
     <div class="input-holder ">
        <form id="bar" role="search" method="GET" class="search-form" action="javascript:randomlink(document.getElementById('abc').value)">
        <input type="text" class="search-input" id="abc"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </html>
```